# Opencv... getting at the data in an IPLImage or CvMat

Tags: python, opencv, iplimage

I am doing some simple programs with opencv in python.  I want to write a few algorithms myself, so need to get at the 'raw' image data inside an image.  I can't just do image[i,j] for example, how can I get at the numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick example of using `LoadImageM` to load an image file directly into a `cvmat`:

```
import cv

path = 'stack.png'
mat = cv.LoadImageM(path, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
x, y = 42, 6
print type(mat)
print mat[y, x]
```

Output:

```
<type 'cv.cvmat'>
(21.0, 122.0, 254.0)
```

---

Quick example showing how to multiple one or more color channels by `0.5`:

```
for x in xrange(mat.cols):
    for y in xrange(mat.rows):
        # multiply all 3 components by 0.5
        mat[y, x] = tuple(c*0.5 for c in mat[y, x])

        # or multiply only the red component by 0.5
        b, g, r = mat[y, x]
        mat[y, x] = (b, g, r * 0.5)
```

Comment: cool thanks... is there a reason behind the order of [y,x]? Also if I want to say, multiply each element by 0.5, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sure thing. The matrix is indexed by `row,col`, and each color tuple is ordered `(B, G, R)` for color images. I'll update the answer to show you how to multiply one or more color components by 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

Both CvMat and IplImage provide `tostring` methods that return a string representing the raw data.  Using the image data, you can figure out how to interpret the string data as a matrix.

You should be able to use `fromarray` to convert the data string back into an image object.

To convert the string to an array, consider using the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module in Python.  For instance:

```
array.array('B', CvMat.tostring()) # 'B' is unsigned char, for rgb8 images
```

To get the 'stride' between pixels, use:

```
stride = CvMat.step / CvMat.cols
```

Then typical array indexing to get individual pixels.  You would probably want to wrap all this up in a class that hides all the nasty complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know opencv python bindings, but in C or C++ you have to get the buffer pointer stored in IplImage. This buffer is coded according to the image format (also stored in IplImage). For RGB you have a byte for R, a byte for G, a byte for B, and so on.

Look at the API of python bindings,you will find how to access the buffer and then you can get to pixel info.

my2c